# Reuse Child Component Method to Parent Component Fabric React - SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I am using Fabric React with SPFx. I want to use one component public method to another component. How can be possible to reuse method?

My Parent Component:

```
export class PanelSmallRightExample2 extends React.Component<
{
...
  public _onShowPanel1()
  {
    alert("other");
  }; 
}
```

Accessing Parent method into child:

```
import { PanelSmallRightExample2 } from './PanelExample_1';

let panelExample = React.createElement(PanelSmallRightExample2);
```

**now, by "panelExample" object not accessible my child method.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the '**static**' keyword in your class definition. I have tried below in my test environment and it works superfine :

```
export class PanelSmallRightExample2 {
    public static _string = ""
    public static _onShowPanel1() {
        alert("other");
    };
}
```

and using them in another web part TS file as:

```
import {PanelSmallRightExample2} from './abc';

let obj1 = PanelSmallRightExample2._string;
let obj2 = PanelSmallRightExample2._onShowPanel1();
```

Comment: @Prashant, Did this resolve your issue?

Comment: Ok I will try. And provide you feedback for the same.